# How to SELECT distinct data with required ORDER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, rdbms

I had created table `t1(ca char(1), cb char(10), test char(20), ord char(20))` and I want to get distinct ca+cb with an order by ord.

To get data I wrote query as:

```
select distinct ca + cb as exp, test
from table
order by ord, exp
```

Error received:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified. `

Also tried to with inner query as

```
select exp, test
from ( select distinct ca + cb as exp, ord, test
from ttemp
order by ord, exp)
```

Error received:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

How can I select `distinct` data with required `ORDER`?

Comment: well, as you have it, you just can't unless you use an aggregation function on `ord`

Comment: use `order by ca+cb`, and ord you can not use. If you want order by ord, add `ord` to select-selected fields ex:`select distinct ca + cb as exp, test, ord
from table
order by ord, ca+cb`.

Comment: on your first query you just need to add *ord* on your select list, then it should work

Comment: @nick_n_a  & @Stephan can not add `ord` in select fields

Comment: you will need to add MIN/MAX *Ord*, otherwise what value will be used out of the duplicates found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `group by`.  Of course, naively, this would be:

```
select (ca + cb) as exp, test
from table
group by (ca + cb), test
order by ord, exp
```

And you will get an error, because `ord`is not in the `select` or `group by`.  So, you need an aggregation function.  For instance:

```
select (ca + cb) as exp, test
from table
group by (ca + cb), test
order by min(ord), exp;
```

I should note that you can trivially solve the problem by including `ord` in the `select`, with either `select distinct` or `group by`:

```
select distinct ca + cb as exp, test, ord
from table
order by ord, exp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query,

```
**select distinct ca + cb as exp, test, ord
from table group by test ord
order by ord, exp**
```

You have not selected ord in the query, but used in the **order by** clause so it will throw an error. Second thing when you are aggregating (sum,count,avg,min or max) with respect to other columns, you have to use **group by** clause